# Deploy nodejs to OpenShift with following directory structure

Tags: node.js, openshift

OpenShift expects the following directory structure for nodejs app.

```
(git repo)
../-- .git
   -- package.json
   --server.js
   --Gruntfile.js
   -- ....
   --/...
```

I have following git repository directory structure.

```
(git repo)
../-- .git
   -- webserver ( nodejs app with package.json and gruntfile resides here)
   -- mobileApp
   -- dbScripts
```

Is it possible to direct OpenShift to consider webserver directory as nodejs app directory?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to move the files in the webserver directory into the root directory of the Openshift gear. That or you could alter your start and stop action hooks in `.openshift/action_hooks/` to start your Nodejs application from within that webserver directory.